# insert string inside <a> tag into other line of code on click

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I want to insert the text contained inside a tag into another spot in the code after clicking on it.

so in a list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">small</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">medium</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">large</a></li>
</ul>
```

When clicking small or any of the listed options I need that string to be placed where it says 'TEXT HERE' below.

```
<li class="that" data-option="{{ get_value:product_options size='TEXT HERE' }}{{ relate:stone_options }}{{ slug }} {{ /relate:stone_options }}{{ /get_value:product_options }}">{{ slug }}</li>
```

It would also have to switch out from the previous clicked option, if small is clicked you get {{ ... size='small' ... }} but when clicking on medium, the word small changes to medium.

I'm not great at javascript dunno if this is an ajax thing or what, help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think it's impossible, because the string in {{}} is native code, so we can't replace it javascript or jquery. If the rendered string (data-option) has some pattern, it maybe possible to replace it. does the rendered string has some pattern to be parsed?

Comment: I think I understand, if it were data-option="option-1" then you could replace option-1 with the clicked item, correct? Maybe I could add a prefix like adding the word option {{ get_value:product_options size='option-TEXT-HERE' }}, then it would be like option-blue or option-green when clicking the menu item

Comment: fyi I have updated my post with some extra detail

Comment: what is the result of {{ get_value:product_options size='TEXT HERE' }}{{ slug }} {{ /get_value:product_options }}? please let me know the rendered string of this code. because, I don't know which framework you are using. if you provide the rendered string, I can find correct solution.

Comment: in an attempt to make the post less confusing I had removed some lines of the code, but now maybe its more confusing. The actual line is {{ get_value:product_options size='TEXT-HERE' }}{{ relate:stone_options }}{{ slug }} {{ /relate:stone_options }}{{ /get_value:product_options }} This fetches data from a content file created by the cms. So under size small get the available stone options and print the slug. So on click small you might get the result data-option="ruby" but on click of medium it could be data-option="amethyst". I will edit the post to reflect this extra bit in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code to solve your problem. just add class to A tag

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="colors">blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="colors">green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="colors">red</a></li>
</ul>

<li class="that" data-option="{{ get_value:product_options 
size='TEXT HERE' }}{{ slug }} {{ /get_value:product_options }}">{{ 
slug }}</li>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

let a = document.querySelectorAll('.colors');
let that = document.querySelector('.that');

// get data-option attribute
let attr = that.getAttribute('data-option');
let atxt;
let aLength = a.lenght;
let i;
for(i = aLength; i >= 0; i--){

    a[i].addEventListener('click',()=>{
        atxt = a[i].textContent;
        // find and replace TEXT HERE with options text
        that.setAttribute('data-option',attr.replace("TEXT HERE",atxt));
    });
  }

</script>
```